# Difference between returning a promise vs returning undefined inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am not really sure I understand the difference between these two common scenarios.

Say we have this:

```
user.save().then(function(val){
   anotherPromise1(val);
}).then(function(val){
   anotherPromise2(val);
}).catch(function(err){

});
```

versus:

```
user.save().then(function(val){
   return anotherPromise1(val);
}).then(function(val){
   return anotherPromise2(val);
}).catch(function(err){

});
```

I know it makes a difference but how exactly?

Comment: take a look at http://kctang.github.io/blog/2015/05/09/understanding-javascript-promise-with-examples-no-more-callback-hell where it provides a few scenarios on how promises can be used.

Comment: Search *solving the puzzle* [here](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), you'll find a section where the author visually shows the difference of timings between several ways of chaining promises (including your two examples).

Comment: You're not "inside" a promise. You're inside a function (hopefully) returning a promise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't return a value from the `then` callback, you're effectively returning `undefined`. The next `then` callback will run immediately, and see `undefined` as the resolution value.

If you return a promise from the `then` callback, the second `then` callback waits on that promise (indirectly, but that doesn't really matter), and when that promise is resolved, gets the resolution value from that promise.

(This is covered by the `then` specification in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40), but slightly by omission — it doesn't explicitly mention what should happen if `onFulfilled` doesn't return anything, but in JavaScript, calling a function *always* gives you a resulting value; if the function doesn't explicitly return something, `undefined` is the result of calling it. JavaScript doesn't have the concept of `void` methods a'la C/C#/C++/Java.)

You can see it in this script [live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20start%20%3D%20Date.now()%3B%0Afunction%20elapsed()%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20rv%20%3D%20String(Date.now()%20-%20start)%3B%0A%20%20while%20(rv.length%20%3C%204)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rv%20%3D%20%220%22%20%2B%20rv%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20rv%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20anotherPromise(type%2C%20val)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Belapsed()%7D%3A%20anotherPromise%5B%24%7Btype%7D%5D%20got%20%24%7Bval%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve(val%20*%202)%3B%20%7D%2C%201000)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20anotherPromise2(type%2C%20val)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Belapsed()%7D%3A%20anotherPromise2%5B%24%7Btype%7D%5D%20got%20%24%7Bval%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve(val%20*%203)%3B%20%7D%2C%2010)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Alet%20user%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20save%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(42)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%2010)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Without%20return%0Auser.save().then(function(val)%7B%0A%20%20%20anotherPromise(%22without%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%7D).then(function(val)%7B%0A%20%20%20anotherPromise2(%22without%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%7D).then(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Belapsed()%7D%3A%20All%20done%60)%3B%0A%7D).catch(function(err)%7B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Auser.save().then(function(val)%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20anotherPromise(%22with%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%7D).then(function(val)%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20anotherPromise2(%22with%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%7D).then(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Belapsed()%7D%3A%20All%20done%60)%3B%0A%7D).catch(function(err)%7B%0A%7D)%3B%0A):

```
let start = Date.now();
function elapsed() {
  let rv = String(Date.now() - start);
  while (rv.length < 4) {
    rv = "0" + rv;
  }
  return rv;
}
function anotherPromise(type, val) {
  console.log(`${elapsed()}: anotherPromise[${type}] got ${val}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(val * 2); }, 1000);
  });
}
function anotherPromise2(type, val) {
  console.log(`${elapsed()}: anotherPromise2[${type}] got ${val}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(val * 3); }, 10);
  });
}
let user = {
  save: () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(42);
      }, 10);
    });
  }
}

// Without return
user.save().then(function(val){
   anotherPromise("without", val);
}).then(function(val){
   anotherPromise2("without", val);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(`${elapsed()}: All done`);
}).catch(function(err){
});

user.save().then(function(val){
   return anotherPromise("with", val);
}).then(function(val){
   return anotherPromise2("with", val);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(`${elapsed()}: All done`);
}).catch(function(err){
});
```

The output is (for example):

```
0015: anotherPromise[without] got 42
0017: anotherPromise2[without] got undefined
0018: All done
0020: anotherPromise[with] got 42
1021: anotherPromise2[with] got 84
1032: All done
```

Note the differences between *without* a return and *with* a return:

- *Without*, `anotherPromise2` was called immediately (as we can see from the elapsed time values) and received `undefined`.
- *With*, `anotherPromise2` waited for `anotherPromise`'s resolution to occur, and then received `84` (`anotherPromise`'s resolution value)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the timing in this matter.

In example 1, the `save` promise is fullfilled and the `anotherPromise1` will be invoked and because there is no promise returned, the `anotherPromise2`will be invoked immediately.

If you return the promise of the `anotherPromise1` function, the invokation of `anotherPromise` will happen, after `anotherPromise1` was resolved.

So example 1: `anotherPromise1` and `anotherPromise2` will be shot simultaneous
While example 2: `anotherPromise2` will wait for `anotherPromise1` to be resolved

Comment: *"So example 1: `anotherPromise1` and `anotherPromise1` will be shot simultaneous"* I think you meant "`anotherPromise` and `anotherPromise2`" (OP's names weren't consistent). No, they won't be simultaneous, they'll be done *in series*, `anotherPromise` then `anotherPromise2`, with `anotherPromise2` receiving the return value of the `onFulfilled` callback containing `anotherPromise`. You said this correctly at the beginning of the answer, just not in the summary at the end. Also, there's the important difference in the resolution value `anotherPromise2` sees, not just timing.