# JQuery animate with promises not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-animate

I have three div boxes with ids `#square`, `#squarebis` and `#squaretris` and I want them to change their background-color to "green" using jQuery color animation.

I want the animation to be sequential: `#square` becomes green first, then `#squarebis`, then `#squaretris`.

I am trying to accomplish this with Javascript Promises and `.then` chaining. Here is my code:

```
//first define the function to wrap the animations into Promises
function animateBox(id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $(id).animate({
                backgroundColor: "green"
            }, 1000, function () {
                resolve()
            });
    })
}

animateBox("#square")
    .then(function () {
        animateBox("#squarebis")
    })
    .then(function () {
        animateBox("#squaretris")
    });
```

the idea was to wrap each animation into a promise and use the `animate` callback to resolve the promise and move on to the next animation in the chain.

This works for `#squarebis`: it waits that `#square` has completed its animation before starting its own. However it does not work for `#squaretris`, i.e. the animations for `#squarebis` and `#squaretris` start at the same time.

The fact that the first step of the chain works makes me think I am close to a solution, but I really do not understand why the second step of the chaining does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between returning a promise vs returning undefined inside a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427028/difference-between-returning-a-promise-vs-returning-undefined-inside-a-promise)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the solution myself. In the chain I was invoking the animations directly. By replacing the final line in my code with:

```
animateBox("#square").then(function(){return animateBox("#squarebis")}).then(function(){
return animateBox("#squaretris")});
```

the animation works as expected

Comment: in `animateBox`, rather than using a promise constructor ... just `return $(id).animate({
                backgroundColor: "green"
            }, 1000).promise();` for example